# How to automatically cast variables in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Here is a example.

```
var tobeCasted = 1;
object data = null;

if (whatIsMyType == typeof(int)) {
    data = (int)tobeCasted;
}
else if (whatIsMyType == typeof(float)) {
    data = (float)tobeCasted;
}
```

However the above code is manually detected each data type.
I'm looking for a one line general solution like following :

```
 data = (whatIsMyType)tobeCasted;
```

Comment: Are your possible type choices within a given assembly? You can do something like that using reflection, as long as you have some scope to search for the types.

Comment: You're immediately [implicitly] casting the object right back to `object` when you store it in `data`, so what are you possibly gaining from this?  Nothing productive is happening here; you're just unboxing and re-boxing the value.

Comment: Your problem here isn't clear, but maybe it can be solved by using generics, and passing `whatIsMyType` as a generic parameter.

Comment: `Eric Lippert` and `Jon Skeet` answered the same question! Who win? Bets are open `:D`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this particular case, I think you want `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
object data = Convert.ChangeType(toBeCasted, whatIsMyType);
```

Of course that only works with a limited set of types - but then so does casting in the first place. If you can tell us more about what you're trying to do, it would be helpful. There may very well be a better approach.

Comment: `ChangeType` will never do anything productive when you put in the object's own type.  It's only purpose is in that it has a set of known conversions between, say, string and the primitives, and between certain types of numeric values, so you could get a `double` even if the input is a string (that could be parsed) or an int or whatever.

Comment: @Mahdi It will compile, and even run, but it's still doing absolutely zero productive work.

Comment: @Servy: In the exact case given though, it would be useful - because when `whatIsMyType` is `float`, it will end up giving a boxed float, which *appears* to be what's wanted. So I disagree with your assessment of "doing absolutely zero productive work".

Comment: @Servy You assume that `whatIsMyType == tobeCasted.GetType`, at which point the code is totally useless since it's equivalent to `data = tobeCasted`.

Comment: @Servy thanks however my data types are limited to primitives only which this works fine.

Comment: This works fine with my data types so no need to give more information about what is my goal. Thanks Jon. Will accept in 3 mins

Comment: @Mahdi - Consider giving more information about your goal for other people who find this question, so it can better help them.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) method. The documentation for the `Convert` class is here; it contains many useful methods for runtime [type coercion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_coercion).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.aspx

That said, try to avoid this if you can. This kind of runtime typing can be considered a bad [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: Beaten by Jon by 42 seconds. :-)

Comment: You don't have to worry. Anyone else that was beaten by 42 seconds would get no upvotes at all. +1 for including documentation and warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sticking the result into a variable of type `Object`, just do that. As you have it now, you're casting to int/float/whatever, then casting to Object. Cut out the middle man.

```
var tobeCasted = 1;
object data = tobeCasted;
```

Comment: The difference is that in the `float` cast, he'll end up with a boxed float, which isn't the same as a boxed int.

Comment: @JonSkeet But he's only casting to float when the object is itself a float, he's not casting to float when the input is `int` or anything like that.

Comment: We don't know where `whatIsMyType` came from. I assumed it was populated from `tobeCasted`, but Jon's correct, it could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is too trivial to understand your real need, but Maybe something like TypeMapper is more suited for your use.